# php - add css class to current month inside 'for' loop

Tags: php

I have the following code snippet to output a list of buttons showing the next 6 months of the year.

```
    <?php

    $curmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1);
    $this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; ++$i) {
        echo '<a href="?d=';
        echo date('Y-m', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month));
        echo '" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning';
        echo '">';
        echo date('F', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month));
        echo '</a>';
        }
    ?>
```

How do I add a css class of 'active' after the current classes to only the current month?
The split echoes are just for my learning and elegibility.

Comment: [do you want like this](https://eval.in/1026934)

Comment: yes, that works fine too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use ternary operator to accomplish this task:

    <?php
            $curmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1);
            $this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));

            for ($i = 0; $i < 6; ++$i) {
                echo '<a href="?d=';
                echo date('Y-m', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month));
                echo '" role="button" '.(($i==0)?'class="active btn btn-sm btn-warning"':'class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"');
                echo '">';
                echo date('F', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month));
                echo '</a>';
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare an empty variable `$class` and set it to "active" if it is the current month, something like this:

```
<?php

$curmonth = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1);
$this_month = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y'));

for ($i = 0; $i < 6; ++$i) {
    $class = '';
    if ( CHECKFORCURRENTMONTH ) {
        $class = ' active';
    }

    echo '<a href="?d=';
    echo date('Y-m', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month));
    echo '" role="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning' . $class;
    echo '">';
    echo date('F', strtotime($i.' month', $this_month));
    echo '</a>';
}
?>
```

You'd obviously need to replace `if ( CHECKFORCURRENTMONTH ) {` with your own check for the current month.